# Partition a list of rules into sublists based on a value string pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, filtering

```
lis={"#49:5"->"#61:7", "#49:5"->"#62:5", "#49:6"->"#61:8", "#49:6"->"#62:4", "#49:7"->"#61:10", "#49:7"->"#62:3", "#49:8"->"#61:9", "#49:8"->"#62:6"}
```

I would like to partition this list of rules into a number of sublists that is based on value string patterns #61:x, #62:y,.... #6n:z

```
clusters=Flatten@DeleteDuplicates@StringCases[Values@mrules,"#"~~cluster__~~":"->cluster]

Out= {61,62}
```

Therefore this list of rules can be split into two sublists (ordering is not required here):

```
 {{"#49:5"->"#61:7", "#49:6"->"#61:8", "#49:7"->"#61:10", "#49:8"->"#61:9"}, {"#49:5"->"#62:5", "#49:6"->"#62:4", "#49:7"->"#62:3", "#49:8"->"#62:6"}}
```

I can also take the list of values sorted

```
Sort@Values@lis

Out = {"#61:10", "#61:7", "#61:8", "#61:9", "#62:3", "#62:4", "#62:5", "#62:6"}
```

Then I experimented with Cases, Split, Select, StringMatchQ, etc without any luck.

Could you please assist me with this problem  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way:

```
label[_ -> s_] := StringReplace[s, "#" ~~ n__ ~~ ":" ~~ __ :> n]
GatherBy[lis, label]

(* Out: {{"#49:5" -> "#61:7", "#49:6" -> "#61:8", "#49:7" -> "#61:10", 
  "#49:8" -> "#61:9"}, {"#49:5" -> "#62:5", "#49:6" -> "#62:4", 
  "#49:7" -> "#62:3", "#49:8" -> "#62:6"}} *)
```

Comment: A very clever and elegant solution indeed, thank you C.E.

Comment: For those who want to avoid `ToExpression[]`: `GatherBy[lis, StringCases[Last[#], "#" ~~ d : DigitCharacter .. ~~ __ :> d] &]`

Comment: @J.M. You posting this made me realize that `ToExpression` was superfluous in the first place, because they're just labels. They're not used for anything other than checking for equality. So I removed it in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just for another approach (based on grouping by "#6n". Using `GroupBy`:

```
lis = {"#49:5" -> "#61:7", "#49:5" -> "#62:5", "#49:6" -> "#61:8", 
   "#49:6" -> "#62:4", "#49:7" -> "#61:10", "#49:7" -> "#62:3", 
   "#49:8" -> "#61:9", "#49:8" -> "#62:6"};
gp = GroupBy[lis, StringTake[#[[2]], {2, 3}] &, Rule @@@ # &];
v = Values[gp]
```

To sort by rule value:

```
f = ToExpression[StringSplit[StringDrop[#, 1], ":"]] &;
SortBy[#, f@#[[2]] &] & /@ v
```

yields:

> {{"#49:5" -> "#61:7", "#49:6" -> "#61:8", "#49:8" -> "#61:9",
>   "#49:7" -> "#61:10"}, {"#49:7" -> "#62:3", "#49:6" -> "#62:4",
>   "#49:5" -> "#62:5", "#49:8" -> "#62:6"}}

Comment: Thank you, always eager to learn new things ;-)

Comment: @Athanassios Παρακαλώ. I voted for C.E. I just wanted to show another way. Mma is versatile. I learn a lot from the creativity of the users on this site myself. :)

Comment: Hi, I studied a bit your code. I noticed that the third argument of GroupBy, i.e. (Rule @@@ # &) can be omitted ??? And I am trying hard to understand this SortBy. Would you be kind enough to provide some analysis, e.g. rewrite it in a more comprehensible way. This  f@#[[2]]& is really too difficult to grasp. Thank you

Comment: I can see that : f /@ Values /@ Values@gp
{{{61, 7}, {61, 8}, {61, 10}, {61, 9}}, {{62, 5}, {62, 4}, {62, 
   3}, {62, 6}}} But I cannot understand how this f@#[[2]]& is applied on Values@gp

Comment: @Athanassios `f@#[[2]&` is just using the function `f`on the second part of the argument. In this case the second argument is the value of the rule. The value is a string (a pair of numbers separate by ':'). `f` converts this into  an expression (numerical) that `SortBy` can use to order. I hope this is clearer. `#` is just a placeholder and `&` is used for completion pure functions.:)

Comment: O.K I got it now, I was confused on the order of evaluation and where exactly this g=f@#[[2]]& is applied. Now I can see that SortBy is applied FIRST on the elements of v, list of rules, and THEN g is applied on the rules. This is what I was trying to get as part of the analysis..... Map[g, Values@gp, {2}] Ευχαριστώ ;-)

Comment: @Athanassios  Yes.  There are many ways to do things in Mma. That is part of the fun. I learn a lot from the creativity on this site. Good luck.  θερμούς χαιρετισμούς :)

Comment: As a final comment and from the student perspective I can now understand that the operational form is often much more clear to use in expressions. I would have used g=f@#[[2]]&, and SoftBy[g] /@ Values @ gp

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
lis = {"#49:5" -> "#61:7", "#49:5" -> "#62:5", "#49:6" -> "#61:8", 
  "#49:6" -> "#62:4", "#49:7" -> "#61:10", "#49:7" -> "#62:3", 
  "#49:8" -> "#61:9", "#49:8" -> "#62:6"}


GatherBy[lis, StringTake[Values@#, {2, 3}] &]
```

or

```
GatherBy[lis, First@StringCases[#, NumberString] &@*Values]
```

---

*Result*

> {{"#49:5" -> "#61:7", "#49:6" -> "#61:8", "#49:7" -> "#61:10",
> "#49:8" -> "#61:9"}, {"#49:5" -> "#62:5", "#49:6" -> "#62:4",
> "#49:7" -> "#62:3", "#49:8" -> "#62:6"}}